# Stuck on two phase simplex where RHS $= 0$

Tags: linear-programming, two-phase-simplex

I'm stuck on the following linear program, it's a minimal example of the problem I'm having:

> Minimize $Z = y$ where $x \ge 1$ and $-2x+y \ge 0$

We start by rewriting this as a system of linear equalities, introducing slack and artificial variables:

$\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
x - s_1 + a_1=1\\
-2x +y - s_2=0
\end{array}
\right.$

We shouldn't need an artificial variable for the second one: $a_1 = 1,s_2=0$ is already feasible.

For phase 1 maximize $p = -a_1 = x-s_1-1$. This gives us the starting tableau

$$
\begin{array}{c|ccccc|c}
&x&y&s_1&s_2&a_1&A\\
\hline
a_1&1&0&-1&0&1&1\\
s_2&-2&1&0&-1&0&0\\
\hline
-p&1&0&-1&0&0&1
\end{array}
$$
With solution $a_1=1/1=1,s_1=0/(-1)=0$

The only positive element in in column 1, so $x$ is the entering variable. The only positive element in this column is in row 1, so $a_1$ is the leaving variable. Pivoting around (1,1) results in the tableau:

$$
\begin{array}{c|ccccc|c}
&x&y&s_1&s_2&a_1&A\\
\hline
x&1&0&-1&0&1&1\\
s_2&0&1&-2&-1&2&2\\
\hline
-p&0&0&0&0&-1&0
\end{array}
$$

With solution $x=1/1=1,s_2=2/(-1) = -2$.

Wait what? How did $s_2$ suddenly become negative? What did I do wrong?

Comment: An artificial variable is necessary for the second constraint! Why not?

Comment: @callculus I thought you added artificial variables to create your initial feasible solution?

Comment: You always introduce artificial variables for equalities and $\geq$-constraints.

Comment: @callculus Ah, that solved my problem, thanks! Is there an enumeration of the full rules somewhere?

Comment: My comment has been deleted. Argh. \\ You´re welcome. It would  make more sense if you search by yourself. Good keywords might be `linear programming` `artificial` `two phase` `-big` (without big). But with the given information I think you are able to solve the most standard linear programming problems. I´m confident about that.

Comment: @callculus Allright, I keep searching around. I'm trying to piece together this algorithm from internet sources and I run into the problem that a lot of sites don't talk much about edge-cases.

Comment: With the edge cases you might be right. You mean `degeneration`? But anyway good luck.

Comment: @callculus Degeneration is one of the things I don't quite understand yet too. Just to make sure I've got the basics down now: assuming $RHS \ge 0$: $\ge$ _always_ surplus and artificial, $=$ _always_ artificial and $\leq$ _always_ slack?

Comment: Upvoted for a nicely typeset tableau.  If you know dual simplex algorithm, you can solve this LP more quickly without using two-phase simplex.

Comment: @GNUSupporter I've been thinking about learning that as well, is it an alternative to two-phase? Is it meant to be done by computers as well?

Comment: It can be performed manually or by computers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How did $s_2$ suddenly become negative? What did I do wrong?

You've chosen the wrong entering variable.  This give rise to an unfeasible solution.

To set up the initial tableau, multiply the second equation of the system
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
x - s_1 + a_1=1\\
-2x +y - s_2=0,
\end{array}
\right.
$$
by $-1$, so that the coefficient of the current basic variable $s_2$ becomes $1$.  This makes the tableau proper.
\begin{array}{c|ccccc|cc}
&x&y&s_1&s_2&a_1&A&\text{ratio}\\
\hline
a_1&1&0&-1&0&1&1 & 1/1 = 1\\
s_2&\fbox{2}&-1&0&1&0&0 & \fbox{0/2 = 0}\\
\hline
p&-1&0&1&0&0&-1
\end{array}
For feasibility reason, one has to pivot around $(1,2)$.
\begin{array}{c|ccccc|c}
&x&y&s_1&s_2&a_1&A\\
\hline
a_1&0&\fbox{1/2}&-1&-1/2&1&\fbox1\\
x&1&-1/2&0&1/2&0&0\\
\hline
p&0&-1/2&1&1/2&0&-1
\end{array}

\begin{array}{c|ccccc|c}
&x&y&s_1&s_2&a_1&A\\
\hline
y&0&1&-2&-1&2&2\\
x&1&0&-1&0&1&1\\
\hline
p&0&0&0&0&1&0
\end{array}
This gives us a feasible *nondegenerate* solution $(x,y) = (1,2)$.

To start phase II, we discard the column representing artificial variable $a_1$, calculate the objective function row, and reuse the rest of the above tableau.

$$\min Z = y \iff \max z = -y$$

\begin{array}{c|cccc|c}
&x&y&s_1&s_2&A\\
\hline
y&0&1&-2&-1&2\\
x&1&0&-1&0&1\\
\hline
z&0&1&0&0&0
\end{array}

To make it a simplex tableau, make the entries representing the current basis zero at the objective function row.

\begin{array}{c|cccc|c}
&x&y&s_1&s_2&A\\
\hline
y&0&1&-2&-1&2\\
x&1&0&-1&0&1\\
\hline
z&0&0&2&1&-2
\end{array}

Therefore, the solution is $(x,y) = (1,2)$ with $Z = -(-2) = 2$.  Note that it is *nondegenerate* and unique because we have strictly positive entries on the RHS and entries representing nonbasic variables at the objective function row.

---

A quicker solution using dual simplex method.

Observe that that $\max z = -y$ has nonpositve coefficients.  This gives rise to a nonnegative objective function row, so optimality is satisfied.  This allows us to use dual simplex method.

Rewrite the LPP as

> $\max z = -y$ where $-x \le -1$ and $2x-y \le 0, x,y \ge 0$.

Note that $y \ge 2x \ge 2(1) \ge 1 > 0$, so adding $x,y \ge 0$ *doesn't* change the problem.

\begin{array}{c|cccc|c}
&x&y&s_1&s_2&A\\
\hline
s_1&\fbox{-1}&0&1&0&\fbox{-1}\\
s_2&2&-1&0&1&0\\
\hline
z&0&1&0&0&0 \\
\text{ratio} & \fbox0 & -
\end{array}

\begin{array}{c|cccc|c}
&x&y&s_1&s_2&A\\
\hline
x&1&0&-1&0&1\\
s_2&0 & -1 & 2 & 1 & \fbox{-2}\\
\hline
z&0&1&0&0&0 \\
\text{ratio} & & \fbox{-1} & -
\end{array}

\begin{array}{c|cccc|c}
&x&y&s_1&s_2&A\\
\hline
x&1&0&-1&0&1\\
y&0 & 1 & -2 & -1 & 2 \\
\hline
z&0&0&2&1&-2
\end{array}

Observe that we arrived at the same tableau much quicker than the usual two phase method.

Comment: Is there a difference between this approach (multiplying the row with $-1$) and @callculus' approach of adding an artificial variable? I.e. will one approach work in some cases where the other doesn't?

Comment: @ToddSewell Both approach *won't* affect the feasibility and optimality of the solution, and they should work without problem as long as you aren't trapped by a cycle.  As you can see from my answer, adding one artificial variable add additional steps.  As a result, adding two artificial variables (callculus's way) is slower than adding one (first part of my answer).  Adding *none* is even better.

Comment: I see. So your genaral solution is to always multiply rows with a $RHS = 0$ by $-1$?

Comment: @ToddSewell My "general" solution for two phase simplex is to create a slack variable (of coefficient one) with $\text{RHS} \ge 0$.  That's the starting point of a simplex method.